# Parallel OpenMP reduction vs. function definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, openmp

I'm using OpenMP but the problem is that I'm declaring/defining a function as follow:

```
void compute_image(double pixel[nb], double &sum)
{
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int j=0;j<640;j++)
    {
    if ...
    sum=sum+pixel[0];
    ....
    }
....
}
```

What I realise now is that :

```
Error   2   error C3030: 'sum' : variable in 'reduction' clause/directive cannot have reference type    C:\Users...\test.cpp    930
```

Actually, I cannot get rid of OpenMP.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a reduction, you could put the `sum=sum+pixel[0]` under a `#pragma omp atomic` or `#pragma omp critical` line.

Another option could be to have a `double local_sum = sum;` before the omp section, reduce on local_sum, and then have `sum = local_sum;` after the for loop.

Comment: Using the second option (local_sum) will likely perform better than using "omp atomic" or "omp critical", because the reduction clause lets each thread have its own local version of local_sum. Using "comp critical" forces the threads to wait in line to update sum, and using"omp atomic" makes the threads contend for the same memory location.